# Does ThreadPoolExecutor in python really work

Tags: python, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to write faster python code using multiple threads. I don't wanna use `ProcessPoolExecutor` for memory consumption preserving.

So, When I use `ThreadPoolExecutor.map` which maps an iterator to a function. It's really not working the time taken by the code is not really enhanced. Then I read about GIL in python, my question is: If GIL is applied to all, why they create  `ThreadPoolExecutor.map`, or is there any better idea to use  `ThreadPoolExecutor.map`.

Please find an example that I use to understand this process. I am happy to hear suggestions in how to use multiple threads for iterator and not multiple process, since my memory card is and cpus are not that high.

```
import concurrent.futures
import math

PRIMES = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293,
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419]

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 4) as executor:
        future= executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)

    print(future.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Multithreading in python for the most part only improves efficiency when there are a lot of blocking I/O operations involved (i.e. a web crawler).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems using threads in python is not a good idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, the `GIL` means that only 1 CPU can be used at a time and there's only 1 "real" thread. So using a thread pool will not speed up CPU-bound code. However, many of the functions in the standard library and other 3rd party libraries will voluntarily release the `GIL` if they get blocked on I/O.

For example, if you have code trying to download lots of things from the internet you could you a Python thread pool. When one thread makes a request to download something and is waiting for the response it can (depending on what library you use to make your HTTP requests) release the `GIL` and give another thread a chance to run. That means you could make many, many requests before any of them complete and then each Python thread will be woken up again when their response is available. That kind of Python multi-threading can result in a huge performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks you. I believe reading that, means in my case that is mainly numerical computation, using threads are not working. I shall look for another approach I read that cython can work in multiple threads efficiency. So, I am going to read how cython can do that

Comment: what about Asynchronous in python, can it work with numerical computation or just web?

Comment: When you call a function that's written in C that C-code can spawn "real threads" and make use of multiple CPUs. That's how "cython can work in multiple threads", but to take advantage of that you'd have to write some C code and then make it available to Python. Python's asynchronous functionality can be used with numerical computation but it still has a GIL and still uses only a single CPU for the *Python* code (as noted - functions implemented in C can always be multi-threaded).

Comment: So much for that ..   Apparently even lowly `javascript` does better since its core libraries are multithreaded at the C level