# How to multithread uploads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

In python I have a list of files that needs to be uploaded.

An example code might look like this:

```
        for path, key in upload_list:
            upload_function.upload_file(path, key)
```

How can I multithread such tasks?

I already came accross multiple solution like process loops, see: [How to Multithread functions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515270/how-to-multithread-functions-in-python)
but to me these seeme to be kinda overkill just to process a list of files for upload. Is there maybe a smarter way?

Comment: I am afraid there is no simpler solution, although there are alternatives (ex. coroutines) but it's "complex" as well

Comment: multithreading isn't difficult. Take a look at ThreadPoolExecutor in the concurrent.futures module

Comment: Unless the file destinations are all different, this won't really run in parallel, no matter how it's coded. This is because it'll end up by being re-sequentialised by the local network interface or the slowest net segment of the route to the destination. For example, if you had 1000 threads to upload 1000 files, all those upload requests are going to take the same amount of time to progress through the NIC / net anyway, and there will be 1000 mostly blocked threads. Threading improves things if there are different dests per file, and the local NIC / net segment isn't the bottleneck to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that complicated with `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
def upload_files(upload_list):
    def __upload(val):
        upload_function.upload_file(*val)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(__upload, upload_list)

upload_files(upload_list)
```

If you can modify `upload_function.upload_file` to receive the `key` and `path` as one parameter the function can be simplified to

```
upload_list = [...]
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(upload_function.upload_file, upload_list)
```

`executor.map(__upload, upload_list)` will run the `__upload` function with one sublist from `upload_list` as parameter, and it will run all of them (almost) simultaneity.

To control the number of threads you can use the `max_workers` parameter

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(upload_list)) as executor:
```

Comment: Will it really run in parallel?

Comment: @bobah Yes, it will. Why do you think it won't?

Comment: Because of the GIL.

Comment: @bobah https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61667111/does-threadpoolexecutor-in-python-really-work. You can also check it easily by printing the values from `__upload`, you will see unsynchronized and a very messy printout.

Comment: Im still kinda confused, please have a look at my whole code, to me its not clear how I can also take the process displayment into this: https://pastebin.com/nXnj8Hdz
I want to display at what point the process currenty is in the list.

Comment: @PeterHammi do you mean the `print("Uploading segment:...` part? you can still do it, but the printout will be messy, as it will run parallelly. What's more important to you? the printout or a shorter run time?

Comment: Fair enought, maybe displaying nothing is the better way to go here. I was already able to sucessfully impement your solution. Cheers!
But how can I do the segment print, any advice, im still very intressted how this works and also why can I put everything just in val and call it with val*?

Comment: Beside, how can I define the number of threads?